# setDiscountAmount not working

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm programatically setting a discount on  my checkout.

I am able to change my grandTotal and subtotal just fine, the problem is with the Discount Amount, it doesnt't matter what I do, the discount message/value won't appear. Any clue on what I am doing wrong?

```
    $totalDiscount = floatval($pixDiscount) * floatval($address->getSubtotal()) / 100;

        

        $address->setSubtotal(0);
        $address->setBaseSubtotal(0);

        $address->setSubtotalWithDiscount(0);
        $address->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount(0);

        $address->setGrandTotal(0);
        $address->setBaseGrandTotal(0);


        $address->setDiscountAmount(0);
        $address->setBaseDiscountAmount(0);


        $address->setGrandTotal($address->getGrandTotal() - $totalDiscount);
        $address->setSubtotal($address->getSubtotal() - $totalDiscount);
        $address->setDiscountAmount($totalDiscount);
        $address->setBaseDiscountAmount($totalDiscount);
  


        $address->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this one :

```
 $address->setSubtotal(0);
 $address->setBaseSubtotal(0);

 $address->setGrandTotal(0);
 $address->setBaseGrandTotal(0);

 $address->collectTotals();


 $quote->setGrandTotal($totalWithDiscount);
 $quote->setBaseGrandTotal($totalWithDiscount);

            
 $address->setQuote($quote);

 $address->setGrandTotal($quote->getGrandTotal());
 $address->setBaseGrandTotal($quote->getBaseGrandTotal());

 $address->setDiscountDescription("DOSCOUNT TITLE");
 $totalDiscount = 50; //YOUR DISCOUNT AMOUNT

 $address->setDiscountAmount($totalDiscount);
 $address->save();
```

Comment: No lucky, still not showing, but thank you.